# CSS - Is it Possible to "Shrink Wrap" a Bounding Block to a Font's Cap and Baseline?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, typography

I have some `<h1>` and `<p>` tags with text content. I'd like the top of the text (cap height) and the bottom of the text (baseline) to be flush with the tag's bounding block. By default there seems to be a certain amount of spacing and I don't know why. Is there a calculation to determine this spacing?

I can achieve what I'm after if I modify the line-height and the height properties of the element, but then the original and desirable line-height for multi-line text overlaps and isn't what we want.

Ex. Right-click a `<p>` tag on this page and hover the element in the dev console to notice that the top/bottom of the text isn't flush with the bounds of the actual `<p>` element.

1. Is it possible to make the cap height and baseline flush with and
   element's bounds?
2. Is this spacing possible to edit in CSS?
3. Is there a rule/calculation that determines what this spacing is?

Comment: I think the answer here is *maybe*, but depends heavily on the font that you're using (and how it's been tuned) as well as how browsers render that font (I'm using http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height as a reference). However, this sounds an awful lot like a requirement that tries to force print design guidelines on the web. The web !== print, and it's going to be very difficult to make it that way.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, I'm very aware that the web `!==` print :) My goal with the question is to determine if this is _possible_. If it is not, then yes we will have to modify our print-based rules (some of which we already know we have to). This is OK and expected, I'm just trying to determine if this specific case is possible.

Answer (score -1):

you want to use something called css reset block

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

and also if your container is a div

use `display:inline;` to wrap exactly onto the element inside.

Comment: I'm currently using a reset block [Eric Meyer's](http://www.cssreset.com/). I tried your example including the addition of the `display:inline;` to the `<h1>` parent `<div>` but I see no change. If I right-click and view in the dev console I'm still seeing the spacing between the font cap/baseline and its bounds. If you're 100% this works could you  provide a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bh5drjju/) If you just double-click the "Heading" or click-and-drag to select it you'll notice the highlighting expands above the cap height and below the baseline. This is the space I'm referring to above. Is it possible to remove that extra space to ensure the `<h1>` bounds are flush with the top and bottom of the text itself?

Comment: you didn't use the reset block there..  once you include the reset block there should be no more extra spaces anywhere  http://jsfiddle.net/bh5drjju/1/

Comment: I think you're missing what I'm saying. Go to the jsfiddle you created with the reset block and 1) select the "header" or "paragraph" text so your cursor actually highlights the text selection 2) zoom the browser window to 300% or so (to see what I'm talking about in detail). You'll notice that there is spacing between the top and bottom of the characters themselves and their containing element. Is there a way to determine what this spacing is? Is there a forumla, or is the space something uncontrollable from a Web Dev perspective?