# Is it possible to vertically center text in its bounding box?

Tags: css

My text is not vertically centered and my designers are pointing it out.

However, I am using the proper CSS to achieve vertical centering, that is not the issue.

The problem lies in the font itself. The glyphs are not centered in the actual text. Selecting the text reveals its bounding box, and from here I can see an uneven amount of space below the text.

[image]

Line-height does not appear to fix this issue. The bounding box is still off, even with a line-height of 0. I can add padding to the top of my elements to attempt to fix this problem, but that's not going to be scalable across the many elements that use this font.

[image: With descender]
It appears that the uneven space is because of descenders. This makes sense, but unfortunately it doesn't get me any closer to figuring out how to truly vertically center this text.

[image]

The font in question is **SouvenirStd-Medium**, but I have noticed this with many other web fonts. It is consistently off no matter which element is used... h1's, paragraph tags, etc.

Although it probably wont be useful, here is an example my styles for headlines:

```
font-family: SouvenirStd-Medium;
font-size: 5rem;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
line-height: 1.3;
letter-spacing: 0;
```

And an example of how I am centering my text in a wrapping  tag.

```
div {
   display: flex;
   height:100px;
   align-items: baseline;
}
```

Comment: *"The problem lies in the font itself."* - Yep...there's no single method to fix this. Any solution is **font-dependent**. If the designers are so insistent, get them to find a font that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: try display: block or something other than inline

Comment: Could you provide the CSS code that you are using?

Comment: It actually looks like it is vertically centered, you just happen to not be using any characters with descenders that drop below the baseline.

Comment: I'm sure theres a canonical typography question somewhere on this...anyone?

Comment: After looking at it with descenders, it is actually a lot closer to centered than I noticed at first. I'll update the example above. As for how I am centering, it's with flexbox and align-items baseline.

Comment: https://designschool.canva.com/blog/typography-terms/ & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671545/css-is-it-possible-to-shrink-wrap-a-bounding-block-to-a-fonts-cap-and-basel?rq=1

Comment: @lostPixels Are you sure `line-height` doesn't work? Can you provide which font you are using? I was able to recreate resolve your problem with Times New Roman using `line-height`: https://jsfiddle.net/y1e92cvh/

Comment: This question would be answerable with the actual CSS code, from which we could propose additions/subtractions. If the font is available for study, that would be answerable. If it is not available, I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: @Quantastical See - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/aL757cLp/1/ Even `line-height` is font-dependent

Comment: Added the font name an example of the rules applied to my headlines. Although I feel like that's barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am also have this issue, where if I use ALL CAPITAL TEXTS, it isn't exactly vertically centered.

Comment: I think that if you're telling the designer to fix a web page's alignment problems for you by choosing a different font (which isn't the one they wanted), then you're just a bad dev who can't do their job. Work with what's given to you and don't make excuses. Find a way to do your job, stop complaining that it's hard.

Answer (score 2):

Line height won't help the issue, as it adds or subtracts equal amount of space to the top and bottom of a single text line, based on the top and bottom spacing defined within the font itself (see [line-height description at w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) for more information). This means that you need to find a different font in order to get what you want without going out of your way.

`padding-top` or `padding-bottom` work great if you use em as the unit, which is relative to the total height of the letter (including the above and below space). That will allow you to shift text by the same relative amount accross the whole webpage, independant of the font-size (and you can use `line-height` from there to manage distance between individual lines):

```
.font-timesnewroman {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
}
```

---

Adapted from a hack I found [in this blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/08/13/one-weird-trick-to-baseline-align-text/), here's a possible solution if the above doesn't work for you (yet also a bit narrow in application):

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: thin dotted gray;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 0px;
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
}
.text::after {
  content:'';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80%; /* adjust this to shift the text */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text">Test</span>
</div>
```

This has the following features and constraints:

- works for elements the above solution doesn't, for example because the elements you're trying to style already have a padding
- allows you to adjust the baseline with percentage or em values (so they do scale with font-size)
- halfway implementable with the after-selector, however requires a span (or other inline-rendered) element around the text to be positioned
- only works for non-wrapping lines