# Center large text vertically in flexbox with align-self: center

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center the number 42 vertically inside its parent div. The parent div has `display: flex` (which I need for other reasons). When I set `align-self: center` on the number, the center of the text is above the center of the div.

I'm guessing this is because it's centering the text as if it had [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender), but in this case I'm only rendering a number so there will never be a descender. The same issue would happen if the text were all uppercase.

How can I make this number appear vertically centered?

```css
.container {
  height: 4.5cm;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #c2fcb6;
}
.child {
  font-size: 96pt;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">42</div>
</div>
```

## Update

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36894309/785404), I found that adding `padding-top: 0.3em` to the `.child` div worked well:

```css
.container {
  height: 4.5cm;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #c2fcb6;
}
.child {
  font-size: 96pt;
  align-self: center;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">42</div>
</div>
```

As the linked answer mentions, the advantage of using em is that you don't have to adjust the value when you change the font size.

Another very important thing I did was use a font a CDN like Google Fonts so that I would get consistent rendering across browsers and platforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to vertically center text in its bounding box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891362/is-it-possible-to-vertically-center-text-in-its-bounding-box) or [Vertically center text that has no descenders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272234/vertically-center-text-that-has-no-descenders/16272609)

Comment: @showdev the first question/answer pair worked; I was able to add `padding-top: 0.3em` to my `.child` and the text now appears centered. It feels hacky to be manually adjusting things like this, but I do like the idea of using em, since it means you don't have to adjust it when you change the font size. The second question/answer is way too out-of-date to be relevant; the web landscape has changed a lot since it was asked/answered.

Comment: I hear you. You might find [Deep dive CSS: font metrics, line-height and vertical-align](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) interesting, specifically the method in [CSS Is Awesome](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align#css-awesome) for approximating adjustments to font metrics by "[computing] vertical-align based on ascender/descender ratio".

Comment: @showdev I'll check those out; thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply the property to the child div but applying `display:flex` to the parent. Try adding `align-items: center;` to the container for making it center for vertical and `justify-content: center;` to align it in center horizontally.

```
.container {
  height: 4.5cm;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #c2fcb6;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child {
  font-size: 96pt;
}


 <div class="container">
      <div class="child">42</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The OP is already vertically centering the text with `display:flex` and `align-self:center`, but reports that "the center of the text is above the center of the div ... because it's centering the text as if it had descenders".

Answer (score -1):

**Does this solve your issue?**

```css
.container {
  height: 4.5cm;
  display:flex;
  background-color: #c2fcb6;
  width:100%;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  
  
}
.child {
  font-size: 96pt;
  
  align-self:center;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">42</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you run this, you can see that the text is not aligned vertically.